# Google Query Set Field As

Tags: sql, function, google-sheets

What I'm trying to do is create compound table using Google Spreadsheets.

Works...

```
=query('Sheet1'!A:F, "select C")
```

Fails...

```
=query('Sheet1'!A:F, "select C,(C/D) as PerItemCost")
```

I'm trying to use the Query function because I'm being lazy. I'd rather not add a G field to Sheet1 that's C/D. If I forget to update it, my report sheet won't show the correct values.

Is there  away to use the traditional (Select column & ' text ' & column) AS NewColumn in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this one out after some time.

You'll use the following format:
Label Field 'Title',Field 'Title'

So, normally it's

```
=query(A:F, "Select A,B,C Label A 'Pinky', B 'Brain', C 'Narf'")
```

The output will be results with Column A labeled as Pinky, Column B labeled as Brain, and so forth.

For my use, I needed something far more complex as I'm calculating fields. So, I needed to reference not just the field, but the calculation I was applying to it. See example below.

Example:

```
=query(A:F,"Select Year(A),Month(A)+1,Day(A),C/D Label C/D 'Cost per Unit', Year(A) 'Year', Month(A)+1 'Month',Day(A) 'Day'")
```

I was hoping that Google would've made it more intuitive, but c'este la vie.